# how to upload images on heroku app using swift

Tags: swift, mongodb, heroku, upload, chat

Hello I am new in the swift . Right now I am dealing with the chat app which is more Challenging to me.Now i have successfully login and register working on app. I am using heroku to upload my code which help me to insert it into the database and help to retrive from the database(created service so that i can call it.). I Am using MongoDB

Now the main issue is i dont know how can i upload the images to the heroku. Using my app. First thing i have free account not the premium one.
Can any one help me. please.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you host your server on Heroku, the key here is not storing a file, storing an URL instead. So you have to upload it to a **STORAGE SERVICE** like Google Storage or AWS ... then get the link to store it in your database. There is two ways:

1. Your client upload image to storage service directly, get the link, send it to your server.
2. Your client upload image to your server, your server upload it to storage service, get the link, store it.

**MY RECOMMENDATION**: let's take a look at **Firebase**, a serverless system developed by Google, you can do so much thing like: social network login, file storage, realtime database that is so fit to an chat app.

Comment: I have a hosting plan on hostinger i can use that storage instead?

Comment: of course you can, just store image somewhere and get the url for using

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Firebase Storage. After initial setup, it is very simple to upload images.

```
// random string generator for image name
let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString

// setup storage reference with name of image file
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("\(imageName).jpg")

// prepare image
let someImage = UIImage(named: "some-image")

// turn UIImage into jpg, 1.0 means no compression
let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someImage, 1.0)

// upload
storageRef.putData(uploadData)
```

You will end up with an URL to access your image like this.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/your-firebase-app.appspot.com/o/image.jpg
```

Comment: Can you share you social id so that i can explain you in detail and show you in detail as its secret project . email. me on nayanjariwala12345@gmail.com